# Invalid argument supplied to foreach using php

Tags: php

```
$numofOfficer = sizeof($_POST['officer']);   // = 2
for ($cntr = 0; 0 < $numOfficer; $cntr++)
{
foreach ($_POST['officer'][$cntr] as $index => $value)
      {
         // DO SOMETHING HERE...
      }
}
```

Please help. I don't how to fix this warning.
The argument of foreach is an array having 2 length and 2 dimension. BUT, the other codes same with this went well, same length and length dimension of array argument. I just cant figure what is difference of the code above to the other.

Comment: Just a typo: you have `0 < $numOfficer` instead of `$cntr < $numOfficer`, which results in incrementing `$cntr` too far since `0 < 2` is always true.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use `for` and `foreach` doing the same. You can omit the `for` and reduce you code to:

```
if (is_array($_POST['officer']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['officer'] as $officer)
    {
       foreach ($officer as $index => $value)
       {
            // DO SOMETHING HERE...
       }
    }
}
```